# How can I implement the following JavaScript closure in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, closures

The following code

```
'use strict';

function blah() {

    if (1 ==21) {
    }
    else {
        var i = 10;
        function inner() {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the following error:

> SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at
>   top level or immediately within another function.

How can I write my function inner such that it has access to my variable 'i'?  According to strict mode I need to move the function to the top but at this point 'i' has not been declared

Comment: That code (specifically the function declaration within a block) isn't strictly valid in any version of ECMAScript. It only works at all because all major browsers implement extensions to ECMAScript to cope with this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Since `var i` will be hoisted to the top of `function blah`'s scope anyway, you could do this:

```
'use strict';

function blah() {
    var i;
    function inner() {
        console.log(i);
    }

    if (1 ==21) {
    }
    else {
        i = 10;
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Where does `inner()` need to be accessible from?  Will this work for your purposes?:

```
var inner = function () { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been declared, since the `var` declares the variable for the entire function, not for the block.

Comment: True, but `function` declarations don't work like `var` declarations.

Comment: @PPvG Which is why the strict warning exists.

Answer (score 1):

The inner function must be declared as a function expression, like so:

```
var inner = function () {
    console.log(i);
};
```